# TinyMCE posts plain text and not html tags

Tags: tinymce

How can tinyMCE configured to post html with it. I am posting the text from the tinyMCE editor onto another page. The posted data shows plain text and not the html which was with the text message. Is it because some configuration has to be set to allow html tags in TinyMCE? This is the code i use

```
<!-- tinymce -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
tinyMCE.init({
        // General options
        mode : "textareas",
        theme : "advanced",
        plugins : "autolink,lists,spellchecker,pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template",

        // Theme options
        theme_advanced_buttons1 : "save,newdocument,|,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,|,styleselect,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect",
        theme_advanced_buttons2 : "cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,search,replace,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,blockquote,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,anchor,image,cleanup,help,code,|,insertdate,inserttime,preview,|,forecolor,backcolor",
        theme_advanced_buttons3 : "tablecontrols,|,hr,removeformat,visualaid,|,sub,sup,|,charmap,emotions,iespell,media,advhr,|,print,|,ltr,rtl,|,fullscreen",
        theme_advanced_buttons4 : "insertlayer,moveforward,movebackward,absolute,|,styleprops,spellchecker,|,cite,abbr,acronym,del,ins,attribs,|,visualchars,nonbreaking,template,blockquote,pagebreak,|,insertfile,insertimage",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
        theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "bottom",
        theme_advanced_resizing : true,
        width: "90%",
        height: "300",

        // Skin options
        skin : "o2k7",
        skin_variant : "silver",

        // Example content CSS (should be your site CSS)
        content_css : "style1.css",

        // Drop lists for link/image/media/template dialogs
        template_external_list_url : "js/template_list.js",
        external_link_list_url : "js/link_list.js",
        external_image_list_url : "js/image_list.js",
        media_external_list_url : "js/media_list.js",

        // Replace values for the template plugin
        template_replace_values : {
            username : "Some User",
            staffid : "991234"
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: TinyMCE should be returning HTML as that's what it's designed to do. I suspect that their may be a problem on the back end as there isn't anything in your config that would strip the HTML. One quick check you can make is to call tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent() method on the page with TinyMCE to see what is returned.

Answer (score 0):

this is a problem in laravel's `{{ $tinyMCE }}`, this prints text only, to print HTML syntax you have to use `{!! $tinyMCE !!}`.

You can also use pure PHP

```php
@php echo $tinyMCE; @endphp
```